# Problem with `dplyr::n_distinct` function

Tags: r

In `n_distinct` Documentation:

> *This is a faster and more concise equivalent of length(unique(x))*

I try:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = c(10, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1), y = c(letters[1:7]))

length(unique(df$x))
#[1] 5

n_distinct(df$x)
#[1] 5
```

And ok. The results are identical.

But:

```
df%>%
  n_distinct(.$x)
#[1] 7
```

What's the problem with a last function?

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Try `df %>% .$x %>% n_distinct()` or `df %>% pull(x) %>% n_distinct()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

`df %>% n_distinct(.$x)`

You are actually doing:

`n_distinct(df, df$x)`

In this case, it will return the number of distinct rows of `df`.

If you remove column `y` note that it will yield the same result as the first two operations:

`df[-2] %>% n_distinct(.$x)`

Result:

`5`

Comment: `n_distinct()` will return the number of distinct rows when multiple vectors are passed to the function, not the number of distinct values of the last column.